# Tiled map generation (removing & adding columns) When?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm making an endless runner like game for iOS, right now I'm at the map generation.

It's working when the map is moving in a fixed speed, it's endless and it's random. I'm using an array to hold the columns of tiles and I remove the first object of the array if it's out of screen, and then I generate a new column at the end of it.

My problem is when I want to increase the speed of the map, the map generation starts to slow and after a while it becomes slower the the map itself, I can't figure it out why.

I created a helper SKSpriteNode which starts at (40,0) and I'm changing its position at the same time as the maps position, and when it's less than or equal to zero I remove a column and generate an other.

The starting mapNode.mapSpeed is 2.0f and I would like to increase it with various values over time.

```
self.helperNode.position = CGPointMake(self.helperNode.position.x+self.mapNode.mapSpeed, self.helperNode.position.y);
self.mapNode.position = CGPointMake(self.mapNode.position.x-self.mapNode.mapSpeed, self.mapNode.position.y);

if (self.helperNode.position.x <= 0.0f) {

    [self.mapNode generateNextColumn];

    self.helperNode.position = CGPointMake(40.0f, 0.0f);

    NSArray *array = self.mapNode.map[self.mapNode.rowCount];
    SKSpriteNode *row = [self.mapNode buildNextRowFromArray:array];
    row.position = CGPointMake((self.mapNode.rowCount*40)-20, 0);
    [self.mapNode addChild:row];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row%li",self.mapNode.rowCount-(long)self.mapNode.children.count];
    SKNode *removableRow = [self.mapNode childNodeWithName:string];
    [removableRow removeFromParent];
}
```

Comment: Where are you checking for the map nodes' position?

Comment: I created a helper node to skip that part, it's moving at the same speed as the mapNode but when its position reaches 0 it resets to (40,0) (i have 40 wide tiles) and thats when i remove a column and generate an other, and my problem is the helper node and map node goes out of sync (the map will be faster than the generation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frequently calling "create/remove node" is rather inefficient. More so if you have to get each row's nodes by string, that's highly inefficient.

You have a fixed number of active sprites (tiles) at any given time, so you should preallocate does sprites and put them in an array or dictionary.

Every column of sprites that has scrolled past the screen border simply get to update their positions (and textures) so they become the next column to appear on the screen.

Comment: With your tips in mind, I implemented a system which preallocates 30 columns as an SKSpirteNode and when 25 of them is out of screen it removes them and fill up the slots with the next columns, so I got 5 columns in case something goes wrong. I would like to ask what do you suggest if i don't want to hard code that 25 and 30? What is the best practice to determine how much column to preload?

Comment: basically divide screen size by sprite size and add 1 (actually: 2) for width/height and you end up with enough tiles to cover the screen plus the "buffer" rows/columns